# MySQL Tuning -- High Memory Usage

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to tune a mysql db using mysqltuner. Mysqltuner is advising that I increase the join_buffer_size and the query_cache_size. At the same time, however, it is warning that my max memory usage is high, which it is at 200%+ of installed RAM (which is 2GB). The bind I'm in is of course that if I do what mysqltuner says, the memory usage will shoot up even higher. So what do I do here? Is the problem rather not with mysql but with the apps running on this server that are evidently requring mysql to do a huge amount of cacheing? How would you mysql administrator experts out there proceed from here? See the mysqltuner report below along with my current [mysqld] settings:

**MySqlTuner report:**

> > MySQLTuner 1.2.0 - Major Hayden 
> >      Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.com/
> >      Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering
>
> -------- General Statistics --------------------------------------------------
>   [--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
>   [OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.5.30-log
>   [OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture
>
> -------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------
>   [--] Status: +Archive -BDB -Federated +InnoDB -ISAM -NDBCluster
>   [--] Data in MyISAM tables: 310M (Tables: 264)
>   [--] Data in InnoDB tables: 8M (Tables: 365)
>   [--] Data in PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA tables: 0B (Tables: 17)
>   [!!] Total fragmented tables: 376
>
> -------- Security Recommendations  -------------------------------------------
>   [OK] All database users have passwords assigned
>
> -------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
>   [--] Up for: 20h 20m 10s (2M q [35.305 qps], 25K conn, TX: 88B, RX: 2B)
>   [--] Reads / Writes: 22% / 78%
>   [--] Total buffers: 480.0M global + 33.5M per thread (110 max threads)
>   [!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 4.1G (203% of installed RAM)
>   [OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/2M)
>   [OK] Highest usage of available connections: 7% (8/110)
>   [OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 150.0M/129.5M
>   [OK] Key buffer hit rate: 100.0% (15M cached / 7K reads)
>   [OK] Query cache efficiency: 74.3% (762K cached / 1M selects)
>   [!!] Query cache prunes per day: 4341
>   [OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (3 temp sorts / 11K sorts)
>   [!!] Joins performed without indexes: 3901
>   [OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 0% (2K on disk / 547K total)
>   [OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (8 created / 25K connections)
>   [OK] Table cache hit rate: 46% (688 open / 1K opened)
>   [OK] Open file limit used: 17% (593/3K)
>   [OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 99% (1M immediate / 1M locks)
>   [OK] InnoDB data size / buffer pool: 8.9M/256.0M
>
> -------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
>   General recommendations:
>       Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
>       MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
>       Reduce your overall MySQL memory footprint for system stability
>       Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes
>   Variables to adjust:
>     *** MySQL's maximum memory usage is dangerously high** 
>      **Add RAM before increasing MySQL buffer variables ***
>       query_cache_size (> 32M)
>       join_buffer_size (> 32.0M, or always use indexes with joins)

**Current mysqld settings in my.cnf:**

> [mysqld]
>   local-infile=0
>   datadir=/var/lib/mysql
>   user=mysql
>   symbolic-links=0
>   port            = 3306
>   socket          = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
>   skip-external-locking
>   key_buffer_size = 150M
>   max_allowed_packet = 160M
>   max_connections = 110
>   wait_timeout = 60
>   query-cache-type = 1
>   query-cache-size = 32M
>   query_cache_limit = 2M
>   thread_cache_size = 16
>   tmp_table_size = 32M
>   max_heap_table_size = 32M
>   join_buffer_size = 32M
>   table_open_cache = 128
>   table_cache = 1600
>   sort_buffer_size = 512K
>   net_buffer_length = 8K
>   read_buffer_size = 256K
>   read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
>   myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
>   innodb_buffer_pool_size = 256M
>   innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
>   innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M

Comment: Simples, add more memory.

Comment: Before doing that, I'd like to verify that something is not wrong or irregular in my setup/configuration.

Comment: 2GB is WAY too little for any type of server. I never go under 16GB these days, especially for a DB one.

Comment: I've run online retail systems processing 300k financial transactions (i.e. updates across multiple tables) and approx 200 times that volume of queries per day on a server with 1Gb - and delivered response times at the browser under 2 seconds per page. It's silly to say that this is "WAY too little". *Usually* adding memory to a server is cheaper option than tuning it - but not always - and there is no "one-size-fits-all" amount of memory / CPU / iops

Answer (score 2):

You've got a rather strange database here - it's doing a lot more writes than reads.

It's really important that you tune your DBMS to run well with Innodb *or* you tune it to run well with MyISAM - but you seem to have a mixture of both table types. You cannot have a DBMS which is optimal with both. You need to start migrating your data onto a single engine. Given the write heavy nature of the database, I'd recommend Innodb.

> Total buffers: 480.0M global + 33.5M per thread (110 max threads)

Currently the risk of running into swap is primarily driven by the per-connection memory usage. but note that this is only a **risk** just now. You also need to establish whether you need 110 concurrent connections - and preferably reduce that a bit. Usually the sort_buffer_size is the main culprit for using up memory per connection - but yours is a quarter of the default.

If you are consolidating on innodb then you need should probably increase the innodb buffer pool size.

You can play around with different values [here](http://www.mysqlcalculator.com/).

Comment: `[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 7% (8/110)` No, I don't think he needs to allow 110 connections...

Comment: ...but the stats are only for a 20 hour period - in the gap between xmas and new year when non-retail sites are very quiet. Yes, it's a valid point, but there's not enough information to say that the metric is representative.

Comment: can you explain to me how you know that the db is doing many more writes than reads?

Comment: `[--] Reads / Writes: 22% / 78%`